# I'm getting exception when trying to connect a web server, How can i solve it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

At the top of MainActivity.java i added two arrays:

```
private final String[] ipaddresses = new String[2];
private final Integer[] ipports = new Integer[2];
```

Then in the onCreate i did:

```
    ipaddresses[0] = "10.0.0.2";
    ipaddresses[1] = "1.0.0.5";
    ipports[0] = 8098;
    ipports[1] = 8088;
    addListenerOnButton();
```

In the addListenerOnButton i did:

```
    public void addListenerOnButton() {
    btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                boolean canConnect = true;
                try {
                    Socket s = new Socket();
                    s.connect( new InetSocketAddress(ipaddresses[0], ipports[0]) );
                    s.close();
                    text.setText("Connection Success");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    canConnect = false;
                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
}
```

When using a break point on the line:

```
s.connect( new InetSocketAddress(ipaddresses[0], ipports[0]) );
```

When it stop on this line and then i click on F11 i'm getting exception in red in the Variables window:

Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate android.system.StructAddrinfo.toString()

Comment: Please edit and post the full stacktrace (logcat) to your question

Comment: How do i get it from the logcat or somewhere else in android studio ? In the logcat it keep scrolling down even if i try to filter it by typing: exception.

Comment: put a breakpoint on `ipaddresses[0] = "10.0.0.2";` in the onCreate-method to be sure it is executed?

Comment: Yes it does. It;s doing both 10.0.0.2 and 1.0.0.5 after pressing F11 on both lines i see that ipaddresses contain {"10.0.0.2", "1.0.0.5"}

Comment: The main idea is when i click the button to loop over the ip's and check which one is the one that my pc is using on the router. In this case 10.0.0.2 and if this is the right one then use this ip. If it dosen't try the next ip address in the array. So maybe it dosent have anything to do with my web server now. All i need is somehow to find on which ip my pc is connected to the router. I give two ip's and i need that my program will loop over them and find which one is my pc on.